# The package name should be ProjectName or CodeName?

Tags: java, namespaces, project, naming

Currently we have a dilemma with my parters with the package naming (java) of our project, the name should be **com.company.projectName** or should be **com.company.codename**??

If our marketing department want to change the name of the project, it's right to change name of the package in the solution? or just change the project name (API, web, etc) that the client see?

Comment: for gods sakes keep the marketing guys out of the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

com.company.projectName

Change the name of the package and the project name. Sets a standard and just makes things easier in the long run for the organization.

Answer (score 0):

I use packages to group similar classes together, so you could name the package something which will give a clue as to what classes are contained in the package.

Answer (score 0):

It´s open to discussion but i would use the shortest possible name (based on the KISS principle), and stick to it even if marketing or anyone else changes the "public name", to avoid version control issues